# Symfony4 Expected String but got String

Tags: string, controller, phpstorm, symfony4

I have this error everywhere in my Controller where I "render" or I access a variable through a `getParameter`:

> `expected "\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\string" got string`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It is not an error of your code, it's a error on your IDE, I assume that you are using PHPStorm, go to File > Invalidate Caches/ Restart .. that should solve it.

Comment: Be sure to set php version to 7 or greater in "Languages & Frameworks > PHP" before.

Comment: I had changed the path of a `.phar` file in PHPStorm settings then received the error. This solution resolved the problem.

Comment: Any idea why this would happen in the first place?